# Is it feasible to use nodejs wrapper(compile-run) to run cpp code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use my cpp functions(the whole code) in nodejs, is it feasible to create a wrapper using compile-run module and use cpp code in nodejs? Please answer. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely possible to use your C++ code in NodeJS, you can implement it using C++ [Addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) to access your code and call certain functions from your C++ code. But unless you really have to, i would suggest just write it in Java-script and use it, as it can get a little complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your response :) Yeah, actually cpp code is too big. So I am just confused between Addons or dll libraries or compile-run module.

Comment: Looked at compile-run modules source code, [here](https://github.com/l-ide/compile-run/blob/master/lib/execute-command.ts) it looks like it's basically just creating a child process and calling the code, i believe Addon is a more native approach. That would be my choice unless i am dealing with a simple interface, which in your case its not if i understand it correctly, so Addon would be my choice if i really have to use C++ code in NodeJS.

Comment: Sorry, troubling you a lot but why not DLL libraries using [node-ffi](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi)

Comment: There is a performance overhead if you are making FFI calls repeatedly, if you are not repeatedly calling you C++ code it should be fine, otherwise Addons is the way to go. take a look at this interesting [benchmarks](http://programminggiraffe.blogspot.com/2014/10/nodejs-ffi-vs-addon-performance.html)

Comment: I am calling cpp code repeatedly, so Addons is the option. Thank you so much for sharing information :)